# Defining a string function without arguments in python

Tags: python

I have defined this function without arguments

```
# Define the function shout
def shout():
"""Print a string with three exclamation marks"""
# Concatenate the strings: shout_word
shout_word = str('congratulations')+ str('!!!')

# Print shout_word
print(shout_word)

# Call shout
shout(hello)
```

I get error when calling the function, what could be the reason?
your assistance would be highly appreciated

Comment: First, fix your indentation. Second, tell us what the error is, rather than making us guess.

Comment: Why are you passing an argument to a function that doesn't accept any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Define the function shout
def shout(word):  # Function shout() takes argument word
    print(str(word) + '!!!')  # Converting to str in case word should be an int

word = 'congratulations'
shout(word)  # Call function shout with variable word.
```

With a second, n_exclamation mark argument to further explain how functions and arguments works:

```
# Define the function shout
def shout(word, n_exclamation=3):  # Function shout() takes argument word and n_exclamation, here n_exclamation is set to 3 in case we do not pass it whne we call shout()
    print(str(word) + ('!' * n_exclamation))  # Converting to str in case word should be an int

word = 'congratulations'
shout(word, 1)  # Call function shout with variable word, print 1 exclamation marks (n_exclamation).
shout(word)  # Call function shout with variable word, will print 3 exclamation marks since we didn't pass any argument to that variable, the function is declared to have a default of 3 when that happens.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Glad I could help